# How to transpose specific columns in a dataframe and get counts for other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
id a1  a2 a3    b1  b2
1   1   0  0    0   1
2   0   0  0    1   0
3   1   1  0    0   1
4   1   0  1    1   1
5   0   1  1    0   0
```

Now, I have to transpose columns beginning with prefix 'a' into rows and get counts for corresponding columns with prefix 'b'. The counts are basically the number of times that 'a' and 'b' co-occurred in an id. Co-occurrence is only if both the values are '1' for that id.

```
    b1 b2 
a1  1  3
a2  0  1
a3  1  1
```

In the above example, a1,b2 pair co-occurred in 3 ids (in id 1,3 and 4) and hence the value is 3.

How to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Matrix multiplication (with python 3.5+)

```
df[['a1', 'a2','a3']].T @ df[['b1','b2']]
```

Update: more generally

```
 df.filter(like='a').T @ df.filter(like='b')
```

Or

```
 df.iloc[:,:3].T @ df.iloc[:,3:]
```

Comment: My actual dataframe is quite large. It has about 2000 'a' columns and 500 'b' columns. Would this be feasible in that case?

Comment: If you are worrying about performance, then don’t. Matrix multiplication probably is the best choice in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am receiving a Memory Error. I have around 300,000 IDs as well.